# Error on applying module:enable command in magento 2.1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm getting below error and have no idea why it's caused by applying a simple command like below:

```
bin> php magento module:enable CustomModuleExt
```

Version:

Magento 2.1.7

Error:

```
The file "/home/mywebsite/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Indexer/IndexerInterfaceFactory.php" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/home/mywebsite/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Indexer/IndexerInterfaceFactory.php): Permission denied
```

What causes this issue and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't infer many clues on what kind of environment setup you've got going but I take it you're on developer mode and from the directory's location I'll assume you're on a shared-hosting aswell with a one-user setup: in that case you should keep certain directories writable and Magento's docs [give you pretty comprehensive guidance for that](http://%20https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-shared):

```sh
cd <magento_root>
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} +
```

In particular, the important part would be this one:

> To use the one-owner setup, you must log in to your Magento server as
> the same user that runs the web server. This is typical for shared
> hosting.

In a multi-user environment: [Set ownership and permissions for two users](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-private)

In this case the issue usually resides in the ownership of those directories, case being it to not belonging to your webserver's group, i.e.: youruser:www-data (for apache2 for example). In that case, your issue would be solved by following step 5:

```
Log in to your Magento server as, or switch to, the Magento file system owner.
Enter the following commands in the order shown:

cd <magento_root>
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```